# Can I confirm if the string is matching with the first block at my regex

Tags: go

I've the below code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "This is a delimited string, so let's go"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(This is a delimited string)|delimited|string`)
    matches := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
    fmt.Println("We found", len(matches), "matches, that are:", matches)
}
```

And getting the output as:

```bash
We found 1 matches, that are: [This is a delimited string]
```

If I changed the `str` in the above code to be:

```golang
str := "This is not a delimited string, so let's go"
```

Then I'm getting the output as:

```bash
We found 2 matches, that are: [delimited string]
```

Both are correct, but in the first block `str` which is having `1 match` is matching `100%` with the first block at my regex, which is `This is a delimited string`, while `str` in the second block showing 2 matches, none of them is matching with my first block at my regex.

Is there a way, so I know if the `str` is matching with the first block at my regex or no, so that I get complete match`or`partial match`is the`len(matches)` is not zero, but the first block at the regex is not matched!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression:

```
(?i)(This is a delimited string)|delimited|string
```

matches the *leftmost longest match* of these literal strings:

- `This is a delimited string`,
- `delimited`, or
- `string`

Feeding the text `This is a delimited string, so let's go` to the regular expression, the 1st alternative matches. It is the only match, because it consumed both `delimited` and `string` — the search continues at the point following the match.

Feeding your alternate text, `This is not a delimited string, so let's go` to the regular expression results in 2 matches, because the 1st alternative does not match, but the 2nd (`delimited`) and the 3rd (`string`) do.

If you want to know *which* alternative matched, simply enclose each alternative in parentheses to make it a *capturing group*:

```
(?i)(This is a delimited string)|(delimited)|(string)`
```

Now we can check the value of each capturing group: if it has a length greater than 1, it's the alternative that matched.

https://goplay.tools/snippet/nTm56_al__2

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "This is a delimited string, so let's go and find some delimited strings"

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(This is a delimited string)|(delimited)|(string)`)

    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)

    fmt.Println("Matches:", len(matches))
    for i, match := range matches {
        j := 1
        for j < len(match) && match[j] == "" {
            j++
        }
        fmt.Println("Match", i, "matched alternative", j, "with", match[j])
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, why if I change the string to be `this is not a ...` I get 4 matches, not 2?

Comment: With `FindAllStringSubmatch()`, the return value is a slice of slices representing all the matches. Each slice in the slice of slices is a match: `match[0]` is the complete match; `match[n]`, where 0 < `n` < `len(matches)`, represents a capturing group's submatch. The capturing group is identified by count left parentheses (`(`) in the regular expression. So in your regex, `match[1]` will be `This is a delimited string`.

Comment: I think I understood you, but not sure, can you pass ruin your code, by making `str := "This is a delimited string, so let's go and find some delimited strings"` and see the 4 lines of output, I think there is a duplication we should have 2 empty and 1 with delimited and one with string, but we are getting 2 of delimited and 2 of string, which I still do not understand why.